# Directory of log files don't exist for docker container. can see path but not actually access file

Tags: docker, logging

I'm working with a docker container and I am trying to access the logs. Currently, my docker container is running my application which prints out info to my command prompt that is running that container. I am trying to access all that information as a file. So far I ran the command to see where my log file is located and something like this came up:
'/var/lib/docker/containers//-json.log'

however, when I do a 'docker exec' into the container. I don't actually have a /lib/ under my /var/ directory! So I ran 'docker logs' to see if there were logs, and the logs I wanted, printed out onto the console. Has anyone encountered anything similar or has any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: I'd start at [View logs for a container or service](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/) in the Docker documentation, and keep reading from there.  You should never be trying to directly access any of the content in `/var/lib/docker`, but it's common enough to set up infrastructure to send these logs somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Storing logs of a container inside a container is anti-pattern . var/lib/docker path is out on the host and not inside the container. Yes you do see the current logs of a running container when you run the following command :

```
 docker exec-it container_id sh
```

But logs for that transaction is only displayed not of previous.

If you are on **linux** : 
`/var/lib/docker` is the path for all docker daemon data and it persists.

If you are on **windows** : 
`C:\programData\docker` is the path for the same.

If you wish to see docker logs , the path is `/var/log/`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `docker logs container_name`
[Docker Logs Document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)